# How to make Active Directory Administrative Center use columns from extraColumns in Display Specifiers?

Tags: active-directory

The extraColumns for the default-Display Display Specifier is not the same as the columns you can chose from in ADAC.

One example of an attribute that is missing is Office (physicalDeliveryOfficeName) which is 
available in Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC) but not in ADAC.

How do you configure which columns are available in ADAC?

Comment: You explained what ADUC is... but what is ADAC?

Comment: I'm sorry, ADAC is the new Active Directory Administrative Center that comes with Windows Server 2008 R2 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes in ADAC, you can read more about it here

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2c551fe5-adc2-4f08-b666-25868112a95e/active-directory-administrative-centeradding-columns

Anyway, if you want to add more columns, right-click on any column in ADAC and click on "select columns..." button. You can add additional columns from list of available columns there.

Comment: I didn't know ADAC was built on PowerShell when I posted the question. It makes sense that it won't use the default-Display Display Specifier then. I mark this as the correct answer since the linked article give good insights into how ADAC works.